# How to get userid by email?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite("sitename"))
  { 
    using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
    {
      string userEmail = "foo@example.com";

      string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(userEmail);

      Console.WriteLine("Your UserName is: " + userName);
    }
  }     
}
```

This code is retuning NULL. What am i doing wrong in this code?

Comment: Depends if you use Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication in SharePoint!!!

Comment: its Forms Authentication in Sharepoint

Comment: It's not a cause of the problem, but do not forget about disposing the `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx

Comment: Please post your `<system.web><membership>` section from your web.config file.  I assume from your comments below that you are using `SqlMembershipProvider`.  I would like to see if there are any configuration issues there.

Comment: @pseudocoder His code is in `using` blocks now, after I edited the question and added them. I didn't want to get into explaining disposal patterns, since it's not what the question is about. Here's the original code: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6345113/4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the simplest answer is that no user was found with that e-mail.  If you believe that is not the case, please show why and I will try to help you out.

Comment: my web config file seems ok too.

Comment: As @pseudocoder says - are you SURE that the email address you are searching for is actually in the sharepoint user list? http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx

Comment: @NaveedAnjum Access the membership database directly (i.e. run a SELECT statement) and check if you can see this email in the `aspnet_Membership` table.

Comment: @Marek , Thanks . i did try to do this and i can see this email.